# click-spam protection with jQuery and Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I want to make a validation (click-spam-protection), if a user clicks on too much links in some seconds.
Let's say I want to restrict one href button of the same type to activate a counter that prevents to be allowed to click on this href button again in 10 seconds.

I have a list of events you can join as a user like the join-button on facebook of an event. But because these event-list is very compact, there are many join-buttons. That's why I want to prevent the user spamming the database by clicking on these join-buttons.

I'm using jQuery in and this is my code:

```
$(function() {
  $(".event_join").click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var uid = <?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>;
    var dataString = 'event_join=' + id + '&uid=' + uid;

    if (uid == '') {
      alert("not logged in");
    } else {
      $("#event_" + id).html('Joining the guestlist...');

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_insert.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
          $("#event_" + id).html('You're on the guestlist!');
        }
      });
    } return false;
  });
});
```

Is it an usual way to validate in the ajax_insert.php file? If yes, how can I tell jQuery it wasn't a "success" and print out the error?

Answer (score 3):

Use 'flag'. Declare 
    var flag = 0;
initially. Then in th code, use it at follows:

```
if(flag==0) {
flag = 1;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_insert.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $("#event_" + id).html('You're on the guestlist!');
        flag=0;
    }
});
```

This way, duplicates can be prevented. And once submitted, you may disable the form using javascript so that the user is not able to send another request.

EDIT 1:
In case you're using  as link, then you can disable the link itself. There are many ways to accomplish this. Like

```
$('.event_join').removeAttr('href');
```

Second way is to change the link address.

```
$('.event_join').attr('href','#');
```

or

```
$('.event_join').attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
```

Third way may be that you make the link hidden.

```
$('.event_join').css({'display':'none'});
```

Fourth way is to remove the link completely.

```
$('.event_join').html('');
```

or better if its parent has just one child,

```
$('.event_join').parent().html('');
```

There can be many more methods, just explore the web.

If you have many links with class event_join, use $('this') instead of $('.event_join') so that not all links get disabled/hidden/removed. A complete code may be:

```
if(flag==0) {
flag = 1;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_insert.php",
    data: dataString,
    context: $(this),
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $("#event_" + id).html('You're on the guestlist!');
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        flag=0;
    }
});
```

The href attribute is removed after success as there may be a chance that ajax request is not completed in the first click itself. And the flag thing is used so as to prevent multiple clicks before the success function is run.

Comment: But I'm not using a form, I'm using an normal < a href > text-link. Is there a solution for this also?

Comment: Of course. Disable the link once clicked. Can be done in many ways: Remove the href attribute using javascript/jquery, or hide the link itself.

Comment: Well nice, here's what Ctrl+R does. You may use user registration and login in such case then, or some better ideas @zeliboba? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505289/ctrlr-in-firefox-for-refreshing-page-and-my-php-code

Comment: Wait a sec, Ctrl+R will resubmit the data in case the form is using just the POST thing. Here the data is submitted using AJAX, so there will be no problem at all. Go with the solution @Vay.

Comment: @k_programmer CTRL+R will reset you idea to clear `href` attribute or similar ideas. Better way is provided in my answer below. Author can solve his task only using server, because a lot of clicks can be done even without a browser at all.

Comment: @zeliboba Your answer is just checking whether the data was successfully submitted to the server or not. The question needs how to handle multiple clicks. Ctrl+R reloads the page basically, so that'll a problem in every case, unless cookies are used and done everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the way you provided. Not clear javascript code, but it works. There are two ways to check response successful or not.

The first one is to parse server response.
In this case for success server result should return something like that:

```
  echo( json_encode( array( 'result' => true ) ) );
  exit();
```

And for error:

```
  echo( json_encode( array( 'result' => false ) ) );
  exit();
```

And on client side server's json reply will be parsed by JQuery automatically. So, handle response like this:

```
success: function( response ){
  if( 'undefined' == typeof response.result ||
      false == response.result ){
    console.log( 'Server returned error. Handle it here' );
  } else {
    console.log( 'Server returned success!' );
  }
}
```

But I prefer to use HTTP response codes because that is what it was made for. The second way to handshake with your server is next. On server side for success:

```
http_response_code( 200 );
echo( 'Good, lets go' );
exit();
```

And for error:

```
http_response_code( 401 );
echo( 'It looks like you are bad boy' );
exit();
```

In this case on client side you can catch server response this way:

```
success: function( response ){
  console.log( 'Server returned http200 code. It means request was success and we do not need even to parse result' );
},
error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
  console.log( 'Server returned error. This could be not only an error you awaiting for, but any other. All error details are provided in incoming variables' );
}
```